# I'd like to make my terminal look like tempered glass

Tags: arch-linux, transparency, hyperterminal

I'd like to make my terminal acrylic looking, like tempered glass.

I installed hyper and installed hyper-acrylic. I followed the instructions and wrote

```
acrylic: {
      blur: "acrylic", // "acrylic" or "classic", anything will be flat
      alpha: 150 // alpha value between 0 and 255
    },
```

I also added the plugin with

```
plugins: ['hyper-acrylic', 'other-plugins'],
```

On the ~/.hyper.js file, however it is not working.

I'm using arch linux.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-acrylic

Comment: As the answer says, its clearly for Windows.  As this question is of no use to future visitors, perhaps you should delete it.

Answer (score 2):

It says right in the title that the plugin is only for Windows 10. Transparent windows are a complex feature heavily dependent on what compositor you are using, so I'm pretty sure it's impossible to run a Windows transparency plugin under Arch.